# crawling loop in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I wanna see and get all the reviews in the google play store using Python. however, I have to click "view more" buttons. I think I need loop.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

SLEEP=5

def pause():
    """pause"""
    time.sleep(SLEEP)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x2080')

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

browser.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsid=com.spotify.music&hl=us&showAllReviews=true")
time.sleep(1)

pause()
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,5500)")
while True:
    button = WebDriverWait(browser,60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """""")))
    button.click()
```

Comment: actually you should `scrollBy` as many times as possible until you meet the "More" button which you will have to click and then repeat `scrollBy` until the end of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note

> execute_script(script, *args) - 
>   Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.

so you just do

1. scroll down
2. check scroll bar is end of page.
3. after down, still scroll bar is end of page, search 'view more' button and click.

and the code

```
lastHeight = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while true:
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(1)    
        newHeight = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        if newHeight != lastHeight:
                #parse new data
        else:
                #button click
                #parse new data
        lastHeight = newHeight
```